# PHP function passing arguuments?

Tags: php, linux

Now I am dealing with PHP but I`ve stucked with a strange issue: 
I am making a simple foo for string length:

```
function slen($str) {
  $len;
  for ( $len=0; $str[$len]; $len++ ) {
          /* while tehre is a symbol in $str continue counting, old C metnod */
   }
   return (int)$len;
}
```

it`s on as a code, and outputs the length but it booms with an PHP warning message :
PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 3 in /home/ilian/Desktop/SERVER/ex4.php on line 5
And on my line 5 is the for loop initialization. So I got that PHP might be confusing by not knowing what kind of variables it checks for TRUE in that array because it can be
"Array",  "HELLO", "MESS", 50 and length is 4 which is correct, but in the case I aam checking a simple string for length. Any easygoing explanation?

Comment: You are aware of the function [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen), right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that at some point your *condition* (`$str[$len]`) will try to access an offset beyond the end of the string. That's your stopping condition, but that stopping condition throws the notice, since accessing an undefined offset is considered an error (and rightly so). You'll need to *check* whether the offset exists using `isset($str[$len])`, which does not throw a notice.

Comment: Nice touch @deceze  I`ve just read about isset empty and unset foos and appears that they are doing the fix... But is there any other thing to check for end of string like C`s "\0" or EOF or NULL or?

Comment: @Ilian No. PHP strings are byte arrays, not `NUL` terminated areas of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write a function to get the length of a string, PHP has this built in for you in several internal functions:

1. [strlen](https://www.php.net/strlen) - Length of a string
2. [mb_strlen](https://www.php.net/strlen) - Length of a string which may have multi-byte characters within it
3. [count](https://www.php.net/strlen) - Length of an array or count of items in an object

If all you need is to count how long a string is, go with [strlen](https://www.php.net/strlen), for arrays you'd use [count](https://www.php.net/strlen). Much better than rolling your own.

Comment: Not exactly... I need a custom version of string length checking.